rammap shows majority of ram is in "large page"
I have a server with 64GB of RAM.
Windows task manager shows RAM usage is at 90%. But none of the processes is using significant RAM. for example, sql server is 500MB, other processes use less.
So I had a look with RAMMAP. I saw that almost all RAM is in the "large page" section. please see screenshot below.
What does this mean? Can someone explain this to me like I'm 5?



haha. it's just an expression.

Its probably your SQL server that is set to use large pages. Go to the "Physical Table" tab and set the filter to "Use" is "Large Page" to check for more detail.

@Silbee thank you. I've added a screenshot of the "physical table" tab to the question. it doesn't seem to be very informational though.

Ok, that is indeed not very helpful.

So, an operating system will divide memory in virtual pages. Typical page size is 4KB, which can result in a large overhead or very fragmented pages causing page cache misses etc. So for memory intensive workloads, there's a mechanism (Large/Huge pages) to set page size to multiple megabytes or even gigabytes. This reduces overhead and page misses resulting in better performance.
I dont know what other software you have running, but MS SQL is a typical usecase for large pages and based on the current information i'm pretty sure MS SQL is responsible for what you are seeing.
